# With which IDE to start to learn Java?

Tags: java

I'm literally asking here with which IDE we should start to practice and which one comes with the most advantages for beginners?

Netbeans or just Notepad?

Comment: Notepad is not a compiler.

Comment: There are lots of options.  Notepad isn't really one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Eclipse, it's and IDE all included. It's also the most used IDE for Java development

https://eclipse.org/downloads/
https://eclipse.org/users/

Don't forget, in order to develop with Java, you need a JDK (Java Development Kit) and not only a JRE (runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1  dowmnload JDK from here
                                                       http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Step 2 definitly go for eclipse as it is more user friendly and more advanced
you can download eclipse luna from here .As with notepad you will have to compile your code using cmd.exe which would be little hard for a novice like you.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/R/eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32-x86_64.zip

Then set environment variables and just start coding......